# YoutubeAPI video sometimes doesn't load in IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, youtube-api

I made website which loads videos by id from database. I am using YoutubeAPI to embed player but in IE player sometimes doesn't load. Here is the script.

```
<script>

var player;
var player_width = $(window).width() - 100;
var player_height = $(window).height() - 50;

$('.prev-next').height(player_height);
$('.prev-next-but').height(player_height);

function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        width: player_width,
        height: player_height,
      videoId: '<?php echo $yt_id; ?>',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
}
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
}
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {        
    if(event.data === 0) {
        document.forms["not_skipped"].submit();
    }
}
```

I don't have this problem, when I am using simple iframe, but I don't know how to trigger event that way when video finishes.

Comment: Yea. Sometimes, <the internet> doesn't work on IE. Seriously, though: _"doesn't load"_: Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: Nope. Player just doesn't appear.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check on the method you're using to load the player API library. If you're using a script tag, chances are that the script loads before your `onYouTubePlayerAPIReady` function is ever defined, and so nothing gets triggered. To avoid such a race condition, you want to load the library like this:

```
<script>
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player;
var player_width = $(window).width() - 100;
var player_height = $(window).height() - 50;

$('.prev-next').height(player_height);
$('.prev-next-but').height(player_height);

function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        width: player_width,
        height: player_height,
      videoId: '<?php echo $yt_id; ?>',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
}
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
}
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {        
    if(event.data === 0) {
        document.forms["not_skipped"].submit();
    }
}
</script>
```

Now, as to another thing you've mentioned -- it's fairly simple to hook the player API into an already existing iframe; you just need to pass the ID of the iframe into the `YT.Player` constructor, and don't give it a width, height, or video id, like this:

```
<iframe id="myplayer" width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/0kl3VNy0uAI?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>    
<script>
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player;

function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('myplayer', {
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
}
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
}
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {        
    if(event.data === 0) {
        document.forms["not_skipped"].submit();
    }
}
</script>
```

Note that we're still loading the player library dynamically, to avoid the race condition.

Comment: With iframe it still doesn't trigger event after video ends and it doesn't autoplay. But it works on IE.

Comment: Whoops -- forgot to mention that, when you have an existing iframe, the source of that iframe MUST include the enablejsapi parameter (set to 1) on the source URL ... this allows you to bind to the iframe events with your code. I've edited the snippet above to reflect that.